# Screen Scrape Static Content

Tags: javascript, screen-scraping

I have a counter on a website whose value I'd like to access using Javascript.

The code I'm trying to reference looks like this:

```
<span id="counter">
0123 // This is the value I'm trying to access
</span>
```

What would be the best way to easily access this value? Screen scraping seems to be overly complex. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var el = document.getElementById('counter'),
    // innerText for IE, textContent for other browsers.
    value = el.textContent || el.innerText || '';
alert(value);
```